# Is "fast web view" working in any browser with Adobe Reader X?

Tags: pdf

I am running WIN7 and have tried with the latest versions of IE, Opera, Safari, Firefox and Chrome and the ALL download the entire file before showing it.

I am monitoring traffic with Fiddler2.

I know that there are questions around here about how to respond for a byte range request from the adobe web plug-in but I am not going there before I see Fast Web View working.

Some links I have found.

http://blogs.adobe.com/pdfdevjunkie/web_designers_guide
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817750/do-most-browsers-make-multiple-http-requests-when-displaying-a-pdf-from-within-t
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Range-Specific-Requests-in-ASP-NET.aspx

Med venlig hilsen / Best regards

Answer (score 5):

A possible reason why you don't see 'fast web view working' may be that you don't test it with the correct PDF files. For fast web view to work, the PDFs need to be *'linearized'* (sometimes also dubbed *'web optimized'*). Most PDFs aren't linearized by default.

Ghostscript and Acrobat Professional (and some other programs) can convert existing PDFs into linearized ones.

---

**Update:** To check a PDF for its properties, run `pdfinfo your.pdf` or `pdfinfo your.pdf | grep Optimized:`. It should say `Optimized:  yes`.

The `pdfinfo` utility is available on Windows, Linux, Mac OS X. The