# wkhtmltopdf rendering twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I'm using wicked_pdf, working fine. However, the server seems to render/execute wicked twice for only one call, resulting in one pdf-file. Can anyone tell me why? The server log looks like this:

```
    2016-03-16T21:53:11.659341+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/wpdf" for 99.99.99.99 at 2016-03-16 21:53:11 +0000
2016-03-16T21:53:11.661184+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SomeStoriesController#wpdf as HTML
2016-03-16T21:53:11.661632+00:00 app[web.1]: ***************WICKED***************
2016-03-16T21:53:11.663620+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered some_stories/wpdf.html.erb (1.1ms)
2016-03-16T21:53:13.128754+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/wpdf" host=xxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=3ca3a32a-2c40-4052-b7fb-8d333b7277c6 fwd="99.99.99" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1477ms status=200 bytes=18490
2016-03-16T21:53:13.132369+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered text template (0.0ms)
2016-03-16T21:53:13.132480+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent data file_name.pdf (0.5ms)
2016-03-16T21:53:13.132673+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 1471ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2016-03-16T21:53:13.362617+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/wpdf" for 99.99.99.99 at 2016-03-16 21:53:13 +0000
2016-03-16T21:53:13.363827+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SomeStoriesController#wpdf as HTML
2016-03-16T21:53:13.364250+00:00 app[web.1]: ***************WICKED***************
2016-03-16T21:53:13.365987+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered some_stories/wpdf.html.erb (1.1ms)
2016-03-16T21:53:14.468550+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/wpdf" host=xxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=5b70cf38-bc29-45fd-8287-3a01b0b1372a fwd="99.99.99.99" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1114ms status=200 bytes=18490
2016-03-16T21:53:14.472015+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered text template (0.0ms)
2016-03-16T21:53:14.472110+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent data file_name.pdf (0.4ms)
2016-03-16T21:53:14.472271+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 1108ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing the same issue.  It is only occurring in Chrome and is not happening in Firefox or IE.

Looks like a bug in Chrome - [Chrome sends two requests when downloading a PDF (and cancels one of them)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725608/chrome-sends-two-requests-when-downloading-a-pdf-and-cancels-one-of-them)

Looks like it will be fixed in v54 of Chrome.