# Chrome generate two request

Tags: spring, google-chrome, chromium

In a spring boot application a link generate a pdf file.

Link in thymeleaf

```
<a th:href="@{/printings/bytesttype/compressions}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><span th:text="#{compressions}">Compressions</span></a>
```

On the controller side

```
@GetMapping(value = "/printings/bytesttype/compressions")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getCompressionsReport() throws IOException, Exception {
        return preparePdfReport(samplingFacade.getCompressionToPrint());
    }

private ResponseEntity<byte[]> preparePdfReport(byte[] content) throws IOException {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
        String fileName = "report.pdf";
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData(fileName, fileName);
        headers.setCacheControl("no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<>(content, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

Actually user click, a request is done.

After another request is done to open with extension

chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/http://localhost:8080/printings/bytesttype/compressions

Is there a way to avoid that?

tried
[Chrome sends two requests when downloading a PDF (and cancels one of them)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725608/chrome-sends-two-requests-when-downloading-a-pdf-and-cancels-one-of-them)

problem still exist

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have to show PDF with the extension (browser inline) you can try adding a header to your HTTP Response as follows:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=report.pdf");
```

Comment: same issue, that fix nothing