# Why does chrome do 2 requests for a pdf file

Tags: google-chrome, http, pdf

Why does chrome always do 2 requests for a pdf file, canceling 1 of them?

[image: Double request of pdf from chrome]

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817750/do-most-browsers-make-multiple-http-requests-when-displaying-a-pdf-from-within-t

Comment: @Malachi I don't think it has anything to do with the 'Accept-Ranges' header mentioned in the link as the second request is simply canceled. It does not even wait for a response.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37600239/32429