# Adobe on Chrome requests PDFs multiple times when opening PDF from URL

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, adobe

I have an issue with my application that appears to be causes by a defect in the Adobe plugin for Chrome. When accessing a PDF from a URL, the Adobe plugin will request the PDF multiple times. This behavior is confirmed with PDFs hosted on unrelated 3rd party servers, such as:

https://css4.pub/2015/icelandic/dictionary.pdf

I have also confirmed that disabling Adobe and using Chrome's built in PDF reader results in the desired behavior of the PDFs only being requested once.

This is a huge problem for my application as we generate PDFs on-the-fly, so this behavior in Adobe on Chrome will cause PDFs to be re-generated multiple times when users access them.

I have researched possible solutions, including some old stackoverflow articles here:

[Chrome sends two requests when downloading a PDF (and cancels one of them)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725608/chrome-sends-two-requests-when-downloading-a-pdf-and-cancels-one-of-them)
[Why does chrome do 2 requests for a pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419721/why-does-chrome-do-2-requests-for-a-pdf-file)

But none of the possible resolutions there about manipulating headers (in particular, the Accept-Range, Max-age) resolve the issue.

The only workaround that does work is to set the response header Content-Disposition: attachment, which causes the browser to just download the file. However, this is not the desired behavior.

Is there any way, through headers or other server side work, that will get Adobe to only request the document once?