# MVC FilePathResult Action causes repeat request in Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, httprequest, http-get

I have an MVC action that is called as follows:

`http://localhost/Report/PrintContainerMasterTrayList?containerMasterId=x&type=downloadview`

The action has the following signature

```
public ActionResult PrintContainerInstanceTrayList(int containerInstanceId, string type)
```

That returns a [FilePathResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filepathresult(v=vs.118).aspx) as follows:

```
return File(filename, "application/pdf");
```

This is all fine except that in Chrome the request fires twice. The request is only made once in Firefox and IE11.

**The original request**

`GET http://localhost/DEV-SAF/Report/PrintContainerMasterTrayList?containerMasterId=x&type=downloadview HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8
Cookie: .ASPXANONYMOUS=-`

**The 2nd request**

`GET http://localhost/DEV-SAF/Report/PrintContainerMasterTrayList?containerMasterId=x&type=downloadview HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost/DEV-SAF/Report/PrintContainerMasterTrayList?containerMasterId=x&type=downloadview
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8`

The response from both requests is the same (in this case up to a 4Mb file that is using excessive bandwidth).

What is causing this behaviour?

**Edit**

The response from the 1st request is 
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: application/pdf
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Set-Cookie: .AUTH=xxxxxx; path=/; HttpOnly
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
Date: Wed, 03 Aug 2016 14:17:41 GMT
Content-Length: 3999`

The response from the 2nd request is 
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: application/pdf
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
Date: Wed, 03 Aug 2016 14:17:46 GMT
Content-Length: 3999`

Comment: Request you paste are not same, for example compare containerMasterId=94101 and containerMasterId=x in query string

Comment: Sorry that was me copy and pasting. Edited the post.

Comment: does those 2 requests fired together or one by one?

Comment: The 2nd request gets fired after the response to the 1st is received.

Comment: I've added the responses. They differ in that the 1st contains a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Content-Disposition header to response in your Action with following content " attachment; filename=test.pdf" or simply "attachment"

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
```

Comment: This does prevent the request from being made twice but only offers the user a download dialog and we want the browser to display the PDF.

Comment: It's look like a known chrome pdf plugin bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587709

Possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817750/do-most-browsers-make-multiple-http-requests-when-displaying-a-pdf-from-within-t

Comment: I was just coming back to comment that I was suspecting the chrome plugin thanks for finding the chrome bug.